# Tutorials to integrate Nami to your website

Tags: nami-wallet, integration

is there a dummy guide on Nami wallet integration into websites?
I have found nami-wallet-api lib by Felippo001. But I can't find any walkthroughs. Specially that I am not familiar with webpack.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this video is helpful? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBfHgIuvHgY

It is a tutorial on how to integrate Nami using this template: https://github.com/cheffNFT/namiwallettemplate

Comment: I watched it. I want hands down on actual server integration. I myself dont know webpack so I am missing major part that is not mentioned in the video. Thanks anyways

Comment: this video is private

Answer (score 1):

you can try using the [`cardano-wallet-interface`](https://github.com/HarmonicPool/cardano-wallet-interface) to handle all the various wallets and not only nami, there are no videos but the [provided documentation](https://github.com/HarmonicPool/cardano-wallet-interface/tree/main/documentation) should be enough.

In any case, consider reading the [CIP-0030](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/tree/master/CIP-0030) if you want to understand how wallet extensions are working.